# How to identify the bottlenecks preventing my program to scale well on a 32 core CPU?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, concurrency, profiling

I have written a program that works just fine. I now want to run 32 independent instances of it, in parallel, on our 32 core machine (AMD Threadripper 2990wx, 128GB DDR4 RAM, Ubuntu 18.04). However, the performance gains are almost null after about 12 processes running concurrently on the same machine. I now need to optimize this. Here is a plot of the average speedup:

[image: Poor concurrent scaling on a 32 core AND Threadripper CPU]

I want to identify the source of this scaling bottleneck.

**I would like to know the available techniques to see, in my code, if there are any "hot" parts that prevent 32 processes to yield significant gains compared to 12**

My guess is it has to do with memory access and the NUMA architecture. I tried experimenting with `numactl` and assign a core to each process, without noticeable improvement.
Each instance of the application uses at most about 1GB of memory. It is written in C++, and there is no "parallel code" (no threads, no mutexes, no atomic operations), each instance is totally independent, there is no interprocess communication (I just start them with nohup, through a bash script). The core of this application is an agent-based simulation: a lot of objects are progressively created, interact with each other and are regularly updated, which is probably not very cache friendly.

I have tried to use linux `perf` but I am not sure what I should look for; also, the mem modules of perf doesn't work on AMD CPU. 
I have also tried using AMD `uProf` but again I am not sure where this system wide bottleneck would appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Take a look at Intel VTune Amplifier as well as Valgrind with cachegrind. Also, it would be nice to see your strong scaling numbers. What do the execution times look like for 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. processes.

Comment: Ok. I've tried to edit the question so that it is more focused on available tools & techniques to identify the bottleneck in the source code, so that I can work on optimizing it. The issue is the question is broad in scope because I am not certain of where the bottleneck is at the system scale. It could also be an unsolvable hardware or OS limitation, I just don't know exactly. I also added a plot to get a better idea of the execution time.

Comment: This is a rather important problem for me. I'd love to know what I can do and improve in this question so that it's not on hold anymore?

Comment: Is your program memory-intensive?  Or can it make good use of the on-chip cache(s)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be the Threadripper architecture. It is 32-core CPU, but those cores are distributed among 4 NUMA nodes with half of them not directly connected to the memory. So you may need to

1. set processor affinity for all your processes to ensure that they never jump between cores
2. ensure that processes running on the normal NUMA nodes only access memory directly attached to that node
3. put less load on cores situated on crippled NUMA nodes

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes I guess it is this architecture that is at the heart of the bottleneck. I've tried using numactl to assig a core to each process (and the corresponding memory node) without much success. For your suggestion 3, I guess that's harder. It would basically means using only half of the CPU cores.